# Can you JOIN two fields with one field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way 2 fieids can join with one field aka:

```
SELECT * FROM Teacher t, Module m INNER JOIN Session s ON t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId AND m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId ... ?
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You seen one of my previous questions on JOINS with Course_Module and Course, If I can Join 2 fields to one field, then I don't have to include Course_Module field in my JOIN which means no duplicates

Comment: You can't expect people to dig through your past question history to figure out what you are asking in a new question. There are lots of people with numeric usernames around. Don't expect anyone to remember you.

Comment: Then please refer back to the question : JOINS in the query end up displaying too many rows? hopefully this will help

Comment: So, you want to delete this question? Each question should stand alone. Don't spread on question among several. Your questions are confusing enough as they are.

Comment: I can delete this question if you refer back to the old question yeah, I will delete this question and go back to the previous question

Answer (score 3):

I think you're joining on two fields with one field each, and absolutely you can do that. If in doubt, try it, the worst thing that can happen is you get an error!

Comment: This. Try things. Run experiments. Don't post to SO without doing some minimal work on your own!

Comment: I have tried it didn't work thats why I thought of asking, maybe it required a different syntax or something. I have been stuck on this situation for about 3 hours by the way as well so I am trying and it is almost 4am in the morning in the UK

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:

```
select *
from Teacher t
join Session s on t.TeacherId = s.TeacherId
join Module  m on m.ModuleId  = s.ModuleId
...
```

Comment: If I do that then nothing will link with ModuleId and I will hit a  dead end

Comment: not necessarily. the t table is connected to the s table by TeacherId, and the m table is connected to the s table by ModuleId.

Comment: But I have no other table that connects either into the t table and I have no other tables connecting from the m table except for Course_Module table but this is will duplicate rows as it will use the ModuleId field to relate

Comment: @user992147: ObscureRobot is right, `Module` is linked to `Teacher` through `Session` so there's no problem.

Comment: @user992147: I have no idea what `Course_Module` is.

Comment: Thats not the problem. The problem is that they are not the only three tables, there are other tables as well. If I do it the way you have told me then how can I link Student Table to this if Student table does not have a teacherId or ModuleId? That is the problem

Comment: Cross Reference table between Course Table and Module Table

Comment: @user992147: Maybe you should update your question to ask what you really want to know and include the schema.

Comment: If you search for question:  JOINS in the query end up displaying too many rows? hopefully this will help? then you will see the whole query and schma. Go on that page and add comments there and I will write back

Answer (score 0):

You can join on two fields, as you did with using `ON` and `AND`. But, what you have here, would be a Cartesian product on the `INNER JOIN` between `Module` and `Session`. So, you will get an error with the on clause because `Teacher t` can't be used there `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.id' in 'on clause'`.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you may want to split this up using multiple `INNER JOIN` clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM Teacher t
INNER JOIN Session s ON s.TeacherId = t.TeacherId
INNER JOIN Module m ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId;
```